# mysql c# unable to connect to host (0x800004005)

Tags: c#, mysql, api

i've got a problem. I cannot connect to a mysql database. This is my errormessage:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException(0x80004005): Unable to connect
>   to any of the specifed MySQL hosts.

The  i think its an misstake in this lines. I cann connect form another extern server via C (same user) to the database.

```
MySqlConnection mdcon;
try
{
    string myConnectionString = String.Format("SERVER={0}; " +
                    "DATABASE={1}; " +
                    "UID={2}; " +
                    "port={3}; " +
                    "PASSWORD={4};", textBox_MD_IP.Text, textBox_MD_dbname.Text, textBox_MD_user.Text, textBox_MD_Port.Text, textBox_MD_pass.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(myConnectionString);
    mdcon = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    mdcon.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Verbindung erfolgreich!");
    mdcon.Close();
}
catch (Exception msg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());  
    throw;
}
```

I would be very happy if somebody can help me.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and see what connection string you are actually using?

Comment: Try this connection string format :
Server=myServerAddress;Port=myPort;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
check whether the server is running, the port is not used by an other app, connection string parameters are corrects, try to change the server port.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Server can be configured to allow for conenctions from localhost only, from localhost and **specified** other computers, or from any computer. Hence check the configuration of the server.
Also, check firewall settings of your local computer.

Comment: As i said.. i can connect from another server with an c programm to the same database (same logins) - Cant use that c programm on my pc because its only usable in linux...

Comment: @user1337: read again! **specified** other computers. Your "another server" is just one of the computers in the list, but not your current computer.

Comment: The User has the rights to connect from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
string myConnectionString = String.Format("SERVER={0};" +
                    "DATABASE={1};" +
                    "UID={2};" +
                    "port={3};" +
                    "PASSWORD={4};", textBox_MD_IP.Text, textBox_MD_dbname.Text, textBox_MD_user.Text, textBox_MD_Port.Text, textBox_MD_pass.Text);
```

I think shouldn't use white-spaces in the connection string.
So change `"DATABASE={1}; "` to `"DATABASE={1};"` and etc.